# Raspberryy pi 3 BLE Devices

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, raspberry-pi3, bluez, bluetooth-lowenergy-4.2

I am new to android.I have Raspberry pi 3 device.I can connect mobile device to Raspberry pi 3 over classic Bluetooth.now i am confused about Raspberry how to connect mobile device to Raspberry over bluetooth low energy.we can connect BLE device to android device and get Characteristics and can write Characteristics.now i want to do same thing in Raspberry pi 3 like (heart rate monitor,MI band 2)

Answer (score 1):

1. Do it using a program

   You can do it programmatically using *DBus Calls*. DBus is an interprocess Communication method used in linux. You can use DBus bindings for different languages such as python or C to make the DBus calls and do the operations.
    *A few links to help you get started :*

   - DBus tutorial - https://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-tutorial.html
   - BLE DBus API - https://elinux.org/images/3/32/Doing_Bluetooth_Low_Energy_on_Linux.pdf
2. Using Gatttool from terminal

   Gatttool is a terminal tool just like hcitool. You can use the following commands to get the thing working:

   - **hcitool lescan**   Gives you the list of nearby Low Energy Devices
   - **gatttool -b *mac_adress_of_le_device* -I**   gives you an interactive session with the mentioned LE device
   - *From the interactive session* give **connect** to connect to the device
   - **primary** to get the primary services.
   - From this result, you can use the *handle* values to get the list of characteristics of a specific service. **characteristics *handle***
   - To get the *value* of a characteristic use **char-read-hnd *handle***
   - To get the *characteristic descriptor*, use **char-desc *handle***
   - to write to a characteristic **char-write-req *handle* *value***

   Hope This helps!